# How to prevent XF86WWAN press from performing rfkill block

Tags: arch-linux, x11, wifi

I would like to use the WiFi kill key (XF86WWAN) from my Thinkpad X1 Carbon for a purpose other than blocking WiFi.

I am using Arch Linux, with a very small WM called bubbles, similar to xmonad.

I can map the key to an action using `xbindkeys`, but so far I haven't found how to prevent blocking the WiFi interface when pressing the key.

Comment: the button may be hardwired to turn the radio on/off ... there should be a BIOS setting for enabling/disabling the button control of the radio

Comment: the `$ rfkill` status for the interface after I press the key is soft blocked. I would think this is a software thing.